# Possible combinations using R

Tags: r, logical-operators, boolean-logic, truthtable

I have edited my question and changed certain lines in my script, to make it clear to find the number of times I can get the output 1 or 0.

I have 19 variables.I tried the possible combinations of these 19 variables for giving a binary output of 0 or 1 i.e. 2 to the power of 19 (5,24,288). But I couldn't display the truth table in R for all the 5,24,288 combinations because of the limited memory space. Is there any way to find the number of combinations that give the output 1 and 0. Below is the script, where I have given the following inputs using logical gate AND and OR. Kindly give me ideas or suggestions to find the number of times I can get  values 0 or 1 as output

```
    n <- 19
    l <- rep(list(0:1), n)
    inputs <- expand.grid(l)
    len <-dim(inputs)
    len <-len[1]
    output <- 1;
    for(i in 1:len)
    {
    if((inputs[i,1] == 1 & inputs[i,2] == 1 & inputs[i,3] == 1 &    (inputs[i,4] == 1 & inputs[i,5] == 1 | inputs[i,6] == 1 & inputs[i,7] == 0)) | (inputs[i,1] == 1 & inputs[i,2] == 1 & inputs[i,8] == 1 & inputs[i,9] == 1) | (inputs[i,1] == 1 & inputs[i,10] == 0 & inputs[i,11] == 0) |(inputs[i,1] == 1 & inputs[i,12] == 1 & inputs[i,13] == 1 & inputs[i,14] == 1) | (inputs[i,1] == 1 & inputs[i,15] == 1 & inputs[i,16] == 1) | (inputs[i,1] == 1 & inputs[i,17] == 0) | (inputs[i,1] == 1 & inputs[i,18] == 1 & inputs[i,19] == 1)){
   output[i] <- 1
   }
   else
   {
   output[i] <- 0
   }
   }
   data <- cbind(inputs, output)
   write.csv(data, "data.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: your question is a bit vague. can you post your final desired output?

Comment: Exactly 1 out of the 2^20 possible Boolean combinations is all true. Surely you don't need a program to determine that.

Comment: Thank you Gregor and moh3n. This is not home work, it is an example I have given here. I am involved in writing a script to show how given n number of genes, how they could possibly interact in different combinations.I don't want to display the output as truth table, I just want to know the number of times, 1 or 0 comes as an output. As I can see, only one time, I will get output 1 as I have used AND operator, when I used AND , OR , I get number of times 1 and 0 as output.Thank you moh3n  and Gregor for working on my script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1048576 isn't absurdly big. If all you want are the 20 0/1 columns it takes about 80 Mb if you use integers:

```
x = replicate(n = 20, expr = c(0L, 1L), simplify = FALSE)
comb = do.call(expand.grid, args = x)

dim(comb)
# [1] 1048576      20

format(object.size(comb), units = "Mb")
# [1] "80 Mb"
```

In your question you use `&&` a lot. `&&` is good for comparing something *of length 1*. Use `&` for a vectorized comparison so you don't need a `for` loop.

For example:

```
y = matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), nrow = 4)
y[, 1] & y[, 2] # gives the truth table for & applied across columns
# no for loop needed
# R will interpret 0 as FALSE and non-zero numbers as TRUE
# so you don't even need the == 1 and == 0 parts.
```

It seems like you're really after the number of combinations where all the values are 1. (Or where they all have specific values.) I'm not going to give away the answer here because I suspect this is for homework, but I will say that you shouldn't need to program a single line of code to find that out. If you understand what the universe of 'all possible combinations' is, the answer will be quite clear logically.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want:

```
key <- c(1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1) # based on your if condition
inputs <- expand.grid(rep(list(0:1), 20))
len <- nrow(inputs)

output <- sapply(1:len, function(i) all(inputs[i,]==key))
data <- cbind(inputs, as.numeric(output))
write.csv(data, "data.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Although, as stressed by others, `key` can be found only in one row out of all 1048576 rows.